# does it run anything after a catch block?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working with SQL Server Express 2012 and I have this stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_AsyncExecActivated]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @h uniqueidentifier
        , @messageTypeName sysname
        , @messageBody varbinary(max)
        , @xmlBody xml
        , @procedureName sysname
        , @startTime datetime
        , @finishTime datetime
        , @execErrorNumber int
        , @execErrorMessage nvarchar(2048)
        , @xactState smallint
        , @token uniqueidentifier;

    begin transaction;
    begin try;
        receive top(1)
            @h = [conversation_handle]
            , @messageTypeName = [message_type_name]
            , @messageBody = [message_body]
            from [AsyncExecQueue];
        if (@h is not null)
        begin
            if (@messageTypeName = N'DEFAULT')
            begin
                -- The DEFAULT message type is a procedure invocation.
                -- Extract the name of the procedure from the message body.
                --
                select @xmlBody = CAST(@messageBody as xml);
                select @procedureName = @xmlBody.value(
                    '(//procedure/name)[1]'
                    , 'sysname');

                update dbo.Configurations with (serializable) set conf_value = 1
                   where sp_name = @procedureName

                   if @@rowcount = 0
                   begin
                      insert dbo.Configurations(sp_name, conf_value) values (@procedureName, 1)
                   end

                save transaction usp_AsyncExec_procedure;
                select @startTime = GETUTCDATE();
                begin try
                    exec @procedureName;
                end try
                begin catch
                -- This catch block tries to deal with failures of the procedure execution
                -- If possible it rolls back to the savepoint created earlier, allowing
                -- the activated procedure to continue. If the executed procedure
                -- raises an error with severity 16 or higher, it will doom the transaction
                -- and thus rollback the RECEIVE. Such case will be a poison message,
                -- resulting in the queue disabling.
                --
                select @execErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
                    @execErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                    @xactState = XACT_STATE();
                if (@xactState = -1)
                begin
                    rollback;
                    raiserror(N'Unrecoverable error in procedure %s: %i: %s', 16, 10,
                        @procedureName, @execErrorNumber, @execErrorMessage);
                end
                else if (@xactState = 1)
                begin
                    rollback transaction usp_AsyncExec_procedure;
                end
                end catch

                select @finishTime = GETUTCDATE();
                select @token = [conversation_id]
                    from sys.conversation_endpoints
                    where [conversation_handle] = @h;
                if (@token is null)
                begin
                    raiserror(N'Internal consistency error: conversation not found', 16, 20);
                end
                update [AsyncExecResults] set
                    [start_time] = @starttime
                    , [finish_time] = @finishTime
                    , [error_number] = @execErrorNumber
                    , [error_message] = @execErrorMessage
                    where [token] = @token;
                if (0 = @@ROWCOUNT)
                begin
                    raiserror(N'Internal consistency error: token not found', 16, 30);
                end
                end conversation @h;
            end
            else if (@messageTypeName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')
            begin
                end conversation @h;
            end
            else if (@messageTypeName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error')
            begin
                declare @errorNumber int
                    , @errorMessage nvarchar(4000);
                select @xmlBody = CAST(@messageBody as xml);
                with xmlnamespaces (DEFAULT N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error')
                select @errorNumber = @xmlBody.value ('(/Error/Code)[1]', 'INT'),
                    @errorMessage = @xmlBody.value ('(/Error/Description)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(4000)');
                -- Update the request with the received error
                select @token = [conversation_id]
                    from sys.conversation_endpoints
                    where [conversation_handle] = @h;
                update [AsyncExecResults] set
                    [error_number] = @errorNumber
                    , [error_message] = @errorMessage
                    where [token] = @token;
                end conversation @h;
             end
           else
           begin
                raiserror(N'Received unexpected message type: %s', 16, 50, @messageTypeName);
           end
        end
        commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int
            , @message nvarchar(2048);
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER()
            , @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            , @xactState = XACT_STATE();
        if (@xactState <> 0)
        begin
            rollback;
        end;

        update dbo.Configurations with (serializable)
            set conf_value = 0
            where sp_name = @procedureName

        raiserror(N'Error: %i, %s', 1, 60,  @error, @message) with log;
    end catch

    update dbo.Configurations with (serializable) set conf_value = 0
                   where sp_name = @procedureName
end
```

I have to do this:

```
update dbo.Configurations with (serializable) 
set conf_value = 0
where sp_name = @procedureName
```

Every time before stored procedure ends. I'll check `dbo.Configurations` to see if `usp_AsyncExecActivated` is running or not.

Do I have to add that `update` on `CATCH BLOCK` and after the `CATCH BLOCK`?

I'm not sure if after catch block runs anything else or it ends stored procedure execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on severity, if there's a session sborting error it will stop executing the procedure. Otherwise, it will continue after CATCH block. See this simplified example:

```
create proc x
as
begin try
    select 1/0
end try
begin catch
    select error_message()
    raiserror (N'Received unexpected message type', 16, 50);
end catch
select 'after catch'
go

exec x;
```

Comment: just to add to a little detail to that: `A TRY…CATCH construct catches all execution errors that have a severity higher than 10 that do not close the database connection.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175976.aspx

Comment: To add to that, errors with severity below 10 are just PRINTs actually.